# Magento catalog filter issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and have set up a new store from scratch. (Have done this before with older versions)

I have been trying to get catalog product filters in my sidebar without any luck. I know this has been asked over and over and the simple answer is to set the 'Is Anchor' option to 'Yes' in the Category setup. I have also set 'Use in Layered Navigation' to 'Filterable (with results)' for all attributes I want to use as filters. Still, the filters do not show up in my sidebar.

When displaying the path hints in my other store, the filters are rendered in 'frontend/default/MY_THEME/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml' but in the new store it looks like this template does not show up at all when showing path hints.

If anyone could point me into the right direction of where to look or how to start finding out what is going on I would be very grateful as I have been stuck for two days now.

Comment: i have an "out of the box" installation of 1.7.0.2 on localhost, and the `catalog/layer/view.phtml` is rendered well in the left column. Did you make any customization to the layout xml files?

Comment: Yes I did but if I change back from my custom theme to the base theme, catalog/layer/view.phtml still does not seem to get rendered

Comment: and what page layout did you set in the category edit?

Comment: I set it to 'No layout updates'

Answer (score 0):

After quite some time of researching as well as trial and error I have found that in my case the issue was caused by disabling `Flagbit_FactFinder` in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable Modules Output`. So if you are having similar problems go to your magento admin panel and check the setting mentioned above.